# Matching two array a user input and random numbers?

Tags: c++

The problem is that the User input numbers although match the random numbers, matches individual numbers from 1 double digit number, for instance:

the user inputs 6 numbers:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

the randomly generated numbers are:

48, 3, 24, 4, 16, 1

The numbers matched in total is: 4 numbers. Integer 1, 2, and 4 is matching but the integer 2 is matching with integer 24 why because within 24 there is a integer 2. I've put it in the array but it still matching. and there's a time my generated random number duplicate and still run.

Our code is supposed to be a Lottery where you are to input 6 numbers, and then generate 6 other random numbers. These must show how many numbers are matched from the random numbers to the user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int size = 6;
const int lotteryDigits = 49;

void generateLottery (int lottoNumbers[])
{
srand(time(0));
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
  {
      int a = 1+(rand()% lotteryDigits);
      lottoNumbers[j] = a;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
  {
      for (int j = i; j <= size; j++)
        {
            if (lottoNumbers[i] == lottoNumbers[j])
            {
                lottoNumbers[j] = (rand() % 49 + 2)/ 2;
            }
        }
  }
}

void generatemyLottery (int myLotto[])
{
cout<<"Input your 6 Lucky numbers (1-49)"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cin>>myLotto[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (myLotto[i] == myLotto[j] || myLotto[i] > 49 || myLotto[i] < 1)
        {
            cout<<"\nInvalid Input"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
}

void matchMaker (int lottoNumbers[], int myLotto[], int hits)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i] == lottoNumbers[j])
          {
              hits++;
          }
      }
  }
}

void displayNumbers (int lottoNumbers[], int myLotto[], int hits, char 
yesOrno)
{
cout<<"Do you want to Draw (Y/N): ";
cin>>yesOrno;

if (yesOrno == 'Y' || yesOrno == 'y')
{
    if (hits > 1 && hits < 1)
    {
        cout<<"You hit "<<hits<<" numbers"<<endl;
    }
    else if (hits == 1 || hits == 0)
    {
        cout<<"You hit "<<hits<<" number"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nBetter Luck next time";
    }
    else if (hits == 6)
    {
        cout<<"You got the JACKPOT";
    }
cout<<"\nYour numbers are"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (myLotto[i] <= lotteryDigits && myLotto[i]>=1)
        {
              cout<<myLotto[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nWinning number are"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<<lottoNumbers[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
    if (yesOrno == 'N' || yesOrno == 'n')
{
    cout<<"\nPlease come again"<<endl;
}
}

int main()
{
int lottoNumbers[6];
int myLotto[6];
char yesOrno;
int choice;
int hits = 0;

while (true)
{
    cout<<"LOTTO\n\n\n";
    cout<<"1. Enter a Number\n";
    cout<<"2. Draw the Numbers\n";
    cout<<"2. Exit\n\n";
    cout<<"Choice: ";
    cin>>choice;

if(choice == 1)
{
    system ("CLS");
    generateLottery (lottoNumbers);
    generatemyLottery (myLotto);
    system ("PAUSE");
    system ("CLS");
}
else if(choice == 2)
{
    system ("CLS");
    matchMaker (lottoNumbers, myLotto, hits);
    displayNumbers (lottoNumbers, myLotto, hits, yesOrno);
    system ("PAUSE");
    system ("CLS");
}
else if(choice == 3)
{
    return 0;
}
else if(choice > 3 || choice < 1 )
{
    system ("CLS");
    cout<<"Invalid Input\n\n";
    system ("PAUSE");
    system ("CLS");
}
else{
    cout<<" \nInvalid Input";
    system ("CLS");
}
}
}
```

the outcome should be

the user inputs 6 numbers:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

the randomly generated numbers are:

48, 3, 24, 4, 16, 1

the supposed matched number is must only 3.
And if there's a way to enhance it feel free to modify it.

Comment: If you sort the input and the generated numbers, you can use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to find the matches. You may also want to look at [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) for picking your numbers

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, when generating the random numbers in `generateLottery()` function, you are not ensuring that the numbers generated are unique, unlike `generatemyLottery()` function, where you check for duplicates and print the string `"Invalid Format"` if you find any. There is some code altering the duplicates in `generateLottery()` function as well, but it does not perfectly ensure that the numbers are unique. This may cause you to have duplicate items in your generated list of numbers, and may cause you to have more hits than you think you are supposed to have, in certain inputs.

Also, there are out-of-bounds operations in `matchMaker()` and `generateLottery()` functions. Specifically, you have `for` loops iterating from index `1` to index `size`, inclusively. Since your arrays are of size `6`, accessing or modifying `myLotto[size]`, or `lottoNumbers[size]` would be accessing somewhere you shouldn't. You may be writing or reading a value outside the bounds of your arrays, which happens to be equal to one of the integers entered by the user, thereby falsely increasing the number of hits you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your matchmaker has multiple problems. First you start from index 1, instead of index 0. Second, is that you are also seeing you are going out of your array's length. I think this might be a reason.

```
void matchMaker (int lottoNumbers[], int myLotto[], int hits)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
      {
          if (myLotto[i] == lottoNumbers[j])
          {
              hits++;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement in this if is always false.

```
if (hits > 1 && hits < 1)
        {
            cout << "You hit " << hits << " numbers" << endl;
        }
```

Hits is only copy of variable from main program when you use it for displayNumbers(). Value of hits from function matchMaker is not saved.
You should return hits value or pass a pointer.

```
int matchMaker(int lottoNumbers[], int myLotto[])
{
    int hits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lottoSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lottoSize; j++)
        {
            if (myLotto[i] == lottoNumbers[j])
            {
                hits++;
            }
        }
    }
    return hits;
}
...
hits = matchMaker(lottoNumbers, myLotto);
```